# Need To check the website contains ssl certificate or not if yes then what is the expire date of the certificate using php scripts

Tags: php, ssl-certificate

I need to check with the php scripts to given website contains ssl certificate or not if it contains then what is the expire date of certificate.

Is there any way to get this information for any website using php scripts?

If yes, then plzzz let me know.  I have tried so many times on google, but I did not find anything.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you should be able to get certificate information by using the `stream_socket_client` function built into PHP.

This particular method works nicely because it doesn't actually make an HTTP request so you don't have to do a `fopen`.

```
$get = stream_context_create(array("ssl" => array("capture_peer_cert" => TRUE)));
$read = stream_socket_client("ssl://www.google.com:443", $errno, $errstr, 30, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $get);
$cert = stream_context_get_params($read);
var_dump($cert["options"]["ssl"]["peer_certificate"]);
```

- [PHP: stream_context_create](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php)
- [PHP: stream_socket_client](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-socket-client.php)
- [PHP: stream_context_get_params](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-get-params.php)

You'll then need to use OpenSSL to work the the certificate information at this point. You can [read about OpenSSL in the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.openssl.php).