# How to detect secure connection (https) using PHP?

Tags: php, security, ssl, https

At the moment I have SSL included on my server. Want to force my users to login using login-page via https.

```
<?php

  if (empty($_SERVER['https']) || $_SERVER['https'] != 'on') {
    header('location: https://my_login_page');
    exit();
    }

  # rest of code
  ...
```

But it's a problem when there's no SSL.

Now I have situation. User requests following URL

```
http://domain.com/login.php
```

Here, I can't access to `$_SERVER['https']` and want to make sure it's possible to redirect user to

```
https://domain.com/login.php
```

For example, SSL certificate expires after some time and want to keep users using login w/out secure connection.

My goal is something like this example:

```
if (ssl_installed() && (empty($_SERVER['https']) || $_SERVER[] != 'on')) {
  header('location: https://domain.com/login.php');
  exit();
  }

# when there's no SSL it continues using HTTP
```

Yes, want to write function (example: `ssl_installed()`) which returns `true` when it's possible using secure connection, otherwise `false`.

I've tried using `get_headers()` and realized it always returns false against `https://` links.

**Possible solution:**

I already have working solution. Config table in my database contains row `ssl=1` (or 0) and after database connection has been established I'm using this value to decide is there possible to use SSL or not and function mentioned above uses this value to return result.

My question is: **Is there simpler solution?**

To be clear: **I'm looking for PHP-ONLY SOLUTION (auto-detection)!**

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a generic config file within all the php files you use? Such as config.php?

Comment: @sjdaws Course yes, there I keep database-account info for using with PDO.

Comment: Is `$_SERVER["HTTPS"]` (capital letters) exists? [PHP doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

Comment: @Passerby - Works with both https and HTTPS on my server. But $_SERVER['HTTPS'] doesn't exist on HTTP request and doesn't tell me is it possible to redirect page to same using https:// instead of http://.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do something like this in your config file rather than editing every script.

```
<?php

// will match /login.php and /checkout.php as examples
$force_ssl = preg_match('/\/(login|checkout)\.php(.+)?/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$using_ssl = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && !empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? true : false;

$url = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if ($force_ssl && !$using_ssl) {

    // redirect to SSL
    header('Location: https://' . $url);

} elseif (!$force_ssl && $using_ssl) {

    // redirect back to normal
    header('Location: http://' . $url);

}
```

Then if your certificate expires, just set `$force_ssl` to `false` in your config file and it'll take care of every script which previously redirected.

---

Now the question has been clarified, you could create a PHP script like this (code taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/4741196/654678)

```
<?php

// get and check certificate
$get = stream_context_create(array("ssl" => array("capture_peer_cert" => TRUE)));
$read = stream_socket_client("ssl://www.google.com:443", $errno, $errstr, 30, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $get);
$cert = stream_context_get_params($read);

$valid = ($cert["options"]["ssl"]["peer_certificate"] != NULL) ? true : false;

// save validity in database or somewhere else accessible
```

Then set up a crontab, or daily task or whatever to hit that PHP script daily. If there is no  certificate, it'll return NULL and be marked as invalid. Check the validity with your script and you're good to go.

Comment: +1 for your effort. I already have similar solution which I use at the moment. I just was looking for a way to automatically determine  SSL on the server, w/out setting SSL state manually (in config, database, etc). Btw, your line with $using_ssl assignment is incorrect because on IIS server $_SERVER['HTTPS'] is ALWAYS set to non-empty value ('on' or 'off') and it CAN'T BE EMPTY if set.

Comment: So you want PHP to detect whether a certificate installed on the server level?

Comment: Dirty solution, but still solution. Even, it's not exactly what I was actually looking for, bottom part of your answer helped me a lot to find solution (using cron). Thanks

Comment: You have a syntax error in the line "$using_ssl = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && !empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? true : false;" , you need to add another ")" before the "? true : false;" part, I cant edit it so I just let you know so you fix it

Answer (score 1):

I think you might solve this with htaccess and these two conditions might help

- RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} on
- RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on

For more info, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1128624/1712686

Comment: +1 Agree with you. Already seen this page. I'm just looking for PHP-only solution if possible.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14760493/detect-ssl-when-proxy-always-claims-a-secure-connection here you have client side redirect

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Return true if HTTPS enabled  otherwise return false
 */
function check_ssl() {
  if ( isset( $_SERVER['HTTPS'] ) ) {
    if ( 'on' == strtolower( $_SERVER['HTTPS'] ) ) {
      return true;
    } elseif ( '1' == $_SERVER['HTTPS'] ) {
      return true;
    }
  }

  if ( isset( $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] )
    && ( '443' == $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] ) 
  ) {
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```